# ConvertTo-SecureString : Capacity Exceeds maximum capacity, encrypt file seems to has max length

Tags: powershell, encryption

Using ConvertTo-SecureString to encrypt an 1MB file and decrypt it, decrypt file size is only 65KB.

Error Message

```
ConvertTo-SecureString : Capacity Exceeds maximum capacity.
Parameter name: capacity.
At XXX
```

So I think that there is a maximum capacity limited for ConvertTo-SecureString, so there are 2 questions:

1. How long can ConvertTo-SecureString Encrypt?
2. How to Encrypt a file over 1MB to a securestring file?

Comment: [The maximum length of a SecureString instance is 65,536 characters.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate string smaller than 65536 length, encrypt it.

And decrypt it one by one solve.